# Github merge PR forked repo into your own repo

Tags: github, forking

I have forked an existing repo into my own repo. Whenever I do a pull request (in my repo), it automatically defaults to the origin repo, and not to the fork I created. How do I get github to default to the repo I created?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to create a bookmark for the exact pull you want to do (assuming you are using the web interface).

Github "knows" that you forked an existing repository. If you have no plans to contribute back to the original repository, "[you can contact Support and request that your fork is turned into a "normal" repository](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile)".